# How to make it change char after "b"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a brute force type program and  it gets too "b" and then just loops "b", i sort of have an idea on what is wrong but not how to fix it
Here is my current code

```
target = input("What is the target word for you to get?\n")

chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
currPos = int()

attempt = chars[currPos]
nxt = currPos + 1

while(attempt != target):
    print (attempt)
    attempt = chars[nxt]
    currPos += 1
    currPos = int(0)

print("Success! \""+ attempt + "\" was the correct password correct!")
```

I know that i am going to have to change the while loop to probably a for loop maybe even containing a while loop. I'm not to sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currPos = int(0) is incorrect.  Simpler to replace the loop with

```
for attempt in chars :
    print(attempt)
```